Optimal monetary policy in IS-MR-PC model
I am trying to work out a formal solution for the central banks' problem in the slightly modified IS-MR-PC model (popularized by Carlin & Soskice (2015) and Carlin & Soskice (2023) textbooks).
The objective function of the central bank is:
$$
L = \min x_t^2 + \beta (\pi_t - \pi^T)^2
$$
The baseline version of the model has the following equations:
\begin{align}
x_t &= - b(r_{t-1}-r_e) \\\\
\pi_t &= \pi_{t-1} + \alpha x_t + \varepsilon^\pi_t
\end{align}
$x_t$ is output gap, $r_t$ and $r_e$ are actual and neutral interest rate, $\pi_t$ is inflation.
One can formally find the CB's FOC for this problem by plugging in the Phillips curve into the objective and differentiating w.r.t. $x_t$:
\begin{align}
x_t &= -\alpha \beta (\pi_t-\pi^T) \\\\
x_t &= -\alpha \beta (\pi_{t-1} + \alpha x_t -\pi^T) \\\\
x_t &= -\frac{\alpha \beta}{1+\alpha^2\beta} (\pi_{t-1} - \pi^T)
\end{align}
Then combine it with the IS curve to obtain the following interest rate rule:
$$
r_t = r_e + \frac{\alpha \beta}{b(1+\alpha^2\beta)} (\pi_t - \pi^T)
$$
Once you have the expression for the interest rate, all other variables can be calculated based on it, hence the system is solved.
I am trying to solve a similar model with a forward-looking IS curve:
\begin{align}
x_t &= E_t x_{t+1} - b(r_{t-1}-r_e) \\\\
\pi_t &= \pi_{t-1} + \alpha x_t + \varepsilon^\pi_t
\end{align}
However, I face difficulty in deriving the interest rate rule in a similar manner. It seems to me that the FOC sould be unaffected, but I do not understand 1) how to express $r_t$ as a function of other variables 2) how to find a closed-form solution for the output gap $x_t$ given that the equation includes a forward-looking component. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
